# Uso prático de Constant scalar expressions no PHP e em outras linguagens

Tags: php, metodologia

No [PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration56.new-features.php) teremos um recurso nomeado `Constant scalar expressions`. [O manual](http://phplobby.com/tag/php-constant-scalar-expressions/) fornece alguns exemplos, mas o foco principal seria:

- Como utilizar corretamente a funcionalidade, sem fazer desa um *anti-pattern*?
- Outras linguagens implementam esse tipo de recurso? Como ele funciona e é utilizado nelas?
- O `variables.less` do Bootstrap seria um exemplo desse conceito?

Comment: Complicado responder por que a própria *feature* já é quase um *antipattern*. Constantes são... caramba, constantes, imutáveis. A partir do momento que você, programador, utiliza variáveis, faz cálculos, altera programaticamente, já não é mais constante. Tanta coisa bacana de se implementar e o pessoal atira no próprio pé desse jeito...

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Você consegue imaginar o pior cenário usando a nova funcionalidade?

Comment: Na minha opinião não existe um pior cenário pois todos eles são ruins. O exemplo que você apresentou pode até fazer algum sentido, mas todo exemplo didático, de certa forma, faz sentido. Mas no mundo real, em APlicações reais eu vejo isso gambiarra.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Constant scalar expressions me parece muito com o que é usado em ``variables.less`` do bootstrap. A finalidade da minha pergunta é entender como Constant scalar expressions é utilizado em outras linguagens para definir quando usaremos esta ferramenta corretamente. Até aqui concordo contigo e espero trabalhar um pouco mais este tema

Comment: Seria bom, então, evidenciar essa pergunta em particular (sobre outras linguagens) porque ela ficou meio perdida no meio do tópico.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, qual sua opinião sobre a alteração da pergunta?

Comment: Veja se a nova redação ficou boa. Enxuguei bastante para focar mais no conceito e na técnica do que na implementação e uso. Qualquer coisa, é só editar de novo e complementar alguma coisa pertinente que possa ter sido cortada em excesso (eu acho que não).

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Vamos ver como ficam as repostas a partir da pergunta da forma que está. Obrigado!

Comment: Concordo com o @BrunoAugusto, não acho que esta feature é algo tão interessante em termos de aplicabilidade e uma nova utilidade, mas sim, mais uma maneira de fazer algo que já era possível no php, acompanhei esta pergunta tentando ser convencido do contrário, mas até agora não.

Comment: Obrigado pela opinião @MarceloAymone. Até agora, vejo o uso da funcionalidade onde mais de uma ocorrência do mesmo valor default é utilizado em mais de 2 parâmetros  de método no mesmo objeto.

Comment: O que aconteceu com os exemplos da pergunta?

Comment: @gmsantos, o BrunoAugusto propôs uma nova formatação da pergunta, simplificando-a. O que achou ?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, qual sua avaliação da resposta dada por neoprofit?

Comment: @MarceloAymone , qual sua avaliação da resposta dada por neoprofit?

Comment: Honestamente, não foi uma resposta ruim, mas faltou ao menos um exemplo prático (e melhor redigido) para ambos os cenários, bom e ruim. Principalmente para o mal uso, já que aquele *App::getPath()* ficou meio fora de contexto pra mim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta funcionalidade não está difundida entre outras linguagens e também não existe uma boa prática encontrada pelo senso comum, portanto minha opinião é que esta nova funcionalidade será muito bem utilizada por alguns e por outros será utilizada como uma nova forma de "gambiarra".

Opinião pessoal:

**Bom uso**:

- Calcular valores padrão para argumentos de métodos;

Neste exemplo, se você quiser alterar o limite padrão, de 5 para 10, mudará em um único lugar:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    const DEFAULT_LIMIT = 5;

    public function bar($limit = self::DEFAULT_LIMIT) {
        //code
    }

    public function wonka($limit = self::DEFAULT_LIMIT) {
        //code
    }
}
```

**Mal uso**:

- Cálculo de urls e paths em constantes, já que isto pode ser utilizado como sempre foi, usando `define()` ou ainda criando objetos e métodos especializados em entregar as informações de Paths por exemplo.

Comment: por favor, melhore seus exemplos de bom e mal uso?

Answer (score 2):

Um exemplo interessante são variáveis de configuração.

Por exemplo: suponha um cenário onde serviços são consumidos, ou de uma base de homologação, ou produção. Esses serviços tem origem através de um URL, que varia, dependendo da base em questão.

Logo, constantes das URLs para esses serviços podem ser determinadas por uma flag que determina se a aplicação está em modo de produção ou homologação. Veja o exemplo a seguir:

```
// variavel que define ambiente - homogação ou produção
$isHomolog = true;

// constantes para ambiente de homologação
const URL_SERVICO_1_HOMOLOG = "http://homolog1.com";
const URL_SERVICO_2_HOMOLOG = "http://homolog2.com";

// constantes para ambiente de produção
const URL_SERVICO_1_PRODUCTION = "http://production1.com";
const URL_SERVICO_2_PRODUCTION = "http://production2.com";

// constantes utilizadas para os serviços
const URL_SERVICO_1 = $isHomolog ? URL_SERVICO_1_HOMOLOG : URL_SERVICO_1_PRODUCTION;
const URL_SERVICO_2 = $isHomolog ? URL_SERVICO_2_HOMOLOG : URL_SERVICO_2_PRODUCTION;
```

Nesse exemplo definem-se constantes para o ambiente de homologação e produção. Além disso, a variável `$isHomolog` identifica se o ambiente é de homologação (valor `true`) ou produção (valor `false`). Logo, as variáveis de serviços utilizadas pelo sistema `URL_SERVICO_1` e `URL_SERVICO_2` tem seu valor condicionado a variável de ambiante `$isHomolog`.

A vantagem desse mecanismo é a não necessidade de trocas de várias URLs no sistema, dependendo do seu ambiante: homologação ou produção.

Note que, o mesmo comportamento pode-ser obtido com variáveis que não são constantes, contudo a criação de constantes garante a não modificação das mesmas pela aplicação. Note que, essa possibilidade de condição na sua criação não é permitida apos as constantes serem definidas, o que garante seu uso correto ao pelo sistema.

Um outro caso interessante é a concatenação de de Strings para criar-se uma constantes. em versões anteriores do PHP, ao tentar criar constantes de Strings baseadas em partes de outras Strings, a seguinte mensagem é mostrada: "PHP Parse error". Agora, isso é permitido. Isso é exemplificado no [link](http://phplobby.com/tag/php-constant-scalar-expressions/) mostrado na própria pergunta. Veja um exemplo a seguir:

```
// Constant declarations
const PHP = "PHP";
const LOBBY = "Lobby";
const PHPLOBBY = PHP . " " . LOBBY;
echo PHPLOBBY . "\n";
echo "\n=====================\n\n";
```

Veja que a constante PHPLOBBY é definida por uma concatenação de Strings. Isso é útil quando constantes são utilizadas no sistema, mas a concatenação da mesma também. Afim de deixar o código mais limpo, uma constante sendo o resultado da concatenação de várias muitas vezes é bem útil. Esse tipo de atribuição para constantes já é possível, tanto em Java quanto em C# .NET.

Comment: Olá @EduardoFernandes! Acredito que este tipo de uso fica melhor com um arquivo de configuração, como o application.ini da instalação da aplicação e não com o cálculo de Constantes.

Comment: Olá @gpupo, note que a variável `$isHomolog` pode ficar em um arquivo .php que pode ser utilizado como arquivo de configurações. O Doctrine e outros frameworks utilizam esse enfoque para recuperar strings de conexão de banco de dados. Além disso o objetivo aqui é mostrar uma possível utilização para Constant Scalar Expression :).

Comment: Eduardo, o objetivo é mostrar o uso ideal e como isto é utilizado em linguagens onde isto já está maduro. Utilizar a funcionalidade para resolver o que já está bem resolvido não é o ideal para mim. Você consegue melhorar a resposta!

Comment: Coloquei mais um exemplo

Comment: Obrigado @EduardoFernandes. Ainda não é a resposta esperada pois até agora você falou sobre possibilidades, o que está bem claro para nós. A principal questão é QUANDO usar a fim de melhorar as técnicas que já utilizávamos antes do PHP 5.6, ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Cara, vou tentar explicar um bom uso com um exemplo.

No código PHP abaixo você pode ver todas as variantes de expressão escalar para codificação PHP, mas vamos falar sobre elas. Temos flexibilidade para usar esse recurso em “Constant declarations”, “Class Constant Declarations”, “Class Property Declarations”, “Argument Declarations”, “Static Variable Declarations”. Como você pode ver o "PHPLOBBY" constante no código PHP abaixo, é resultado da concatenação de "PHP" e "lobby" com espaço vazio constante entre eles.

se você tentar a mesma abordagem em versões anteriores do PHP vai dar "Parse Exception". A coisa mais importante para mim é a flexibilidade nas declarações de argumento. Nós adicionamos exemplo do método em nossa classe "PhpLobby" chamado "is_true". Basicamente o que ele faz é se não passar argumento que execute a "Constant Scalar Expressions" ( "$ c = self :: NÚMERO == 9? "True": "False". )Nós verificamos se a constante "Número" é igual a 9 e depois atribuir um valor a variável $ c que temos flexibilidade para fazer isso apenas em PHP 5.6 e não na versão anterior do PHP.

```
    <?php
echo "\n===PHPLobby Constant Scalar Expressions ===\n";

// Constant declarations
const PHP = "PHP";
const LOBBY = "Lobby";
const PHPLOBBY = PHP . " " . LOBBY;
echo PHPLOBBY . "\n";
echo "\n=====================\n\n";

// Class Constant Declarations
class PhpLobby {
    const PHP = PHP . " ";
    const LOBBY = self::PHP . LOBBY . "\n";
    const NUMBER = 5 + 4 . "\n";

    // static variable declarations
    static $math = 5 + 4 . "\n";
    static $math2 = 9 - 5 . "\n";
    static $math3 = self::NUMBER - 4 . "\n";

    // class property declarations
    public $php = "PHP " . "Lobby\n";
    public $number = 5 + 4 . "\n";

    // argument declarations
    function is_true($c = self::NUMBER == 9 ? "True" : "Wrong") {
        return $c . "\n";
    }
}
echo PhpLobby::LOBBY;
echo PhpLobby::NUMBER;
echo "\n=====================\n\n";

// Class Property Declarations
$phpLobby = new PhpLobby();
echo $phpLobby->php;
echo $phpLobby->number;
echo "\n=====================\n\n";

// Argument Declarations
echo $phpLobby->is_true(); // weeeeee magic!
echo $phpLobby->is_true(10); // result will be 10 as expected
echo "\n=====================\n\n";

// Static Variable Declarations
echo PhpLobby::$math;
echo PhpLobby::$math2;
echo PhpLobby::$math3;

echo "\n===========================================\n";
?>
```

Além disso, aqui tem a lista do que pode ser usado com ele:

Supported operation:

1. - – Addition
2. - – Subtraction
3. - – Multiplication
4. / – Division
5. % – Modulus
6. ! – Boolean Negation
7. ~ – Bitwise Negation
8. | – Bitwise OR
9. & – Bitwise AND
10. ^ – Bitwise XOR
11. << – Bitwise Shift Left
12. >> – Bitwise Shift Right
13. . – Concatenation
14. ?: – Ternary Operator
15. <= – Smaller or Equal
16. => – Greater or Equal
17. == – Equal
18. != – Not Equal
19. < – Smaller
20. > – Greater
21. === – Identical
22. !== – Not Identical
23. && / and – Boolean AND
24. || / or – Boolean OR
25. xor – Boolean XOR

Supported Operands

1. 123 – Integers
2. 123.456 – Floats
3. “foo” – Strings
4. **LINE** – Line magic constant
5. **FILE** – File magic constant
6. **DIR** – Directory magic constant
7. **TRAIT** – Trait magic constant
8. **METHOD** – Method magic constant
9. **FUNCTION** – Function magic constant
10. **NAMESPACE** – Namespace magic constant
11. <<

    <<<’NOWDOC’ – NOWDOC string syntax

    SOME_RANDOM_CONSTANT – Constants

    class_name::SOME_CONST – Class constants

E se quiser saber mais, vai no site deles mesmo:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs

Espero ter ajudado! Abraços!

Comment: oi @Dante! Obrigado pela resposta. Se você olhar o histórico das edições da pergunta, verá que este exemplo que você usou fazer parte da própria pergunta, mas que decidimos retirar para simplificá-la. Você precisa nos dizer como esta funcionalidade é utilizada em boas práticas em outras linguagens onde já é madura.