# Definição de valor numérico em Constantes PHP

Tags: php

Posso usar o comando define() para definir um valor numérico a uma constante? Todos os exemplos que pesquisei somente utilizam strings, há problema em definir um valor numérico?

Comment: pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: define('CONSTANTE', 1);
eu sempre encontro exemplos do tipo define('CONSTANTE', 'string')

Comment: Pode sim, é boa prática para evitar números mágicos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O uso de constantes ajuda a evitar o problema dos números mágicos que é a repetição de um valor em várias instrução que não faz muito sentido, no lugar de cara ocorrência troca-se por uma constante.

um exemplo é o número 7, talvez a primeira coisa que venha a cabeça são os dias da semana e que tal 86.400 qual é o significado? esses dois números podem ser trocados por constantes

```
define('DIAS_DA_SEMANA', 7);
define('DIA_EM_SEGUNDOS', 86400);
```

Até o php5.5 constantes só eram suportadas com valores escaleres(string, int, double, bool) nenhuma operação(concatenação) podia ser feita.

O php5.6 introduziu um novo recurso chamado constantes escalares onde é possível definir o valor de uma constante atráves de expressões, chamadas de funções, operação e também permite definir como um array.

```
define('ano', 2015); //valida em todas as versões;
define('ano', date('Y')); //valida a partir da versão 5.6
```

[Exemplo - ideon](http://ideone.com/ELBItd)

Leitura recomenda:

[Uso prático de Constant scalar expressions no PHP e em outras linguagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25606/91)

[Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de declarar constantes como array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52779/91)

[Qual a diferença entre define() e const](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45806/91)

Answer (score 1):

Pode sim, inclusive até mesmo o PHP utiliza alguns números em constantes como por exemplo as constantes de níveis de erro.

```
echo E_ALL;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo E_NOTICE;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo E_DEPRECATED;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo M_PI; // Constante matemática PI
```

Saída:

```
32767
8
8192
3.1415926535898
```